# Division of administrator's rights between persons

Tags: oracle, security

For our application we're using outsorced Oracle administration. Now we'd like to prevent external oracle administrator from changing our data (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE).

Is there any way how to do it?

Is there possible to REVOKE eg. UPDATE ANY TABLE to SYS account and is this sufficient?

I have read the Oracle Security Guide but haven't found anything. Only a statement: Do not use a DBA role which contains eg. the UPDATE ANY TABLE privilege.
I see I also should REVOKE GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE ...
Simply I'd need a complex guide how to do it and I'm not able to find any document about it.

Thanks

Comment: Messing with `SYS` at all seems like a realy bad idea. What do the external admins need to be able to do - can you create new accounts and roles for them, with just the privs they actually need?

Comment: The oracle database is outsourced also by a company that runs and administers the database. I'd like that foreign administrator should create new user, backup data etc. but wouldn't be able to drop or insert/update/delete records in a table.